# Removing adjacent duplicates from array PHP ignores first element with value 0

Tags: php, arrays

I have following code to remove adjacent duplicates from an array

```
$myArray = array(
                    0 => 0,
                    1 => 0,
                    2 => 1,
                    5 => 1,
                    6 => 2,
                    7 => 0,
                    8 => 0,
                );

            $previtem= NULL;
            $newArray = array_filter(
                $myArray,
                function ($currentItem) use (&$previtem) {
                    $p = $previtem;
                    $previtem= $currentItem;
                    return $currentItem!= $p ;
                }
            );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

**Problem**

Required Output.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 0
)
```

Actual output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 0
)
```

How to get required output  without modifying my code much?? or is there any other better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) in your filter function. When you say

```
return $currentItem != $p ;
```

PHP is treating the initial null value of `$p` and the 0 value of `$currentItem` as equivalent, so the first iteration gets filtered out.

If you change the line to use strict comparison instead (`===` or `!==`), it will work as expected

```
return $currentItem !== $p ;
```

This ensures only adjacent values that are *exactly* the same, including type comparison, are filtered.

See https://eval.in/1019471

Comment: Oh yes! overlooked it. Thanks